# How can configuration values be encrypted in October CMS

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I am planning to work on a new Project and exploring October CMS as a prominent choice. It has great features and plugins. One thing I did not really find there is - how can I keep my secret data, like database connection strings, safe?

All the documentation says that we keep the configurations in config files which are part of the source code. But I want to be kept secret in an encrypted format. I did not find any clue in my so far research. Does anyone know if there is a way to do this in October CMS?

Comment: put them in environment files (.env ) more info=> https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/configuration. and this files is not needed to be part of source code.

Comment: There is the Crypt facade that allows encryption of values. You can learn about that [here](https://octobercms.com/docs/services/hashing-encryption#encryption)

Answer (score 0):

Secret data (like database strings) are already safe from view in a typical OctoberCMS application.

But if you're looking to keep the data out of version control, consider using the [DotEnv configuration](https://octobercms.com/docs/setup/configuration#dotenv-configuration). You can execute `php artisan october:env` from the project root, which will create a `.env` file and will automatically update your config files so that they refer it.

A few other suggestions:

- **Make sure your .env file is [not committed to version control](https://dev.to/somedood/please-dont-commit-env-3o9h).** It will be unique for each installation of your application anyway.
- **[Cache configuration values on production](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/configuration#configuration-caching)** as part of your deployment routine with `php artisan config:cache`, and make sure `APP_DEBUG` is false on production so that sensitive values aren't displayed when application errors are encountered.
- **Consider using a [public folder](https://octobercms.com/docs/setup/configuration#public-folder)** for production environments for improved security.

If you're still looking to encrypt strings in the `.env` file or other configuration files anyway, you can review the method described here and see if it would work for you:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/using-the-crypt-facade-in-the-config-files